# Implement LEX program by using EBNF & Syntax diagram

Tags: c, compiler-errors, flex-lexer, lex, ebnf

I have created the following syntax diagram and EBNF meta-language structure of it.

[image]

My ENBF structure,

```
var_part = var [identifier { "," identifier } ":" type "κ" { }].

identifier = letter { letter | digit }.

type = "integerKG" | "realKG" | "charKG" | "booleanKG".

letter = "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" | "E" | "F" | "G" | "H" | "I" | "J" | "K" | "L" | "M" | "N" | "O" | "P" | "Q" | "R" | "S" | "T" | "U" | "V" | "W" | "X" | "Y" | "Z" | "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g" | "h" | "i" | "j" | "k" | "l" | "m" | "n" | "o" | "p" | "q" | "r" | "s" | "t" | "u" | "v" | "w" | "x" | "y" | "z".

digit = "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9".
```

I want to create the LEX program of it. So far, I created the following:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
%}


type integerAK|charAK|booleanAK|realAK
var [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]
comma {var}(", "{var}):" "{type}"Θ"
order var" "{comma}(" "{comma})


%%
{order} printf("Correct Syntax");
.* printf("Invalid Syntax");
%%
```

I am receiving EOF error and I can't find what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean "I am receiving EOF error"? In response to what? And please copy the exact text of the error message.

Comment: I assume you meant that you received the error "EOF encountered inside an action" when you tried to process that file with Lex. If the file you pasted is really what you gave lex, that's not too surprising. Take a careful look at the first line: `/* Definitions/`. Do you see something missing? Also look at the lines `/User code section/` and `/Rules/ `. Probably you intended those to be comments. Do they look like they would be taken as comments by a C compiler?

Comment: Mmm, sorry. Made some edits and removed the comments. The EOF error disappared but I have many declare errors. I will check it again. I am new in LEX programming so please excuse my faults. Thank you for your advices.

Comment: Lex only matches regular expressions, not context-free grammars such as EBNF describes.  So you'll need a parser as well as a lexer.